# Can I use IDLE to debug a program that reads from standard input?

Tags: python, debugging, python-idle

I'm debugging a long source code file that takes many inputs from the keyboard. I want to step through the program to see variable values, but I can't get the Python IDLE debugger to take standard input.

I'm aware I can have my source code read a file with the inputs, but I do not want to replace all my input calls with line reads. Can I have the IDLE debugger read standard input while a program is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The following worked for me on Win10 with 3.12.0b2.  Use the [over] button on the debug window to step over the IDLE wrappers for `input` and `print`.  When the input prompt, here `?` , appears, click on Shell to make it the active window so keypresses are detected and displayed.  Hit `Return` as usual to end input and return control to your program.

```
>>> [DEBUG ON]
>>> while True:
...     s = input('? ')
...     print(s)
... 
? ttt
ttt
? rrrrr
rrrrr
```